# How to refactor some classes from the maven project into a separate module

Tags: spring-boot, maven, javaparser

I was recently tasked to separate some classes along with all the dependencies and properties, etc from a spring boot microservice project into another new spring boot microservice project. I did it by hand but there were too many redundant things copied (properties, deployment config). I would like to automate the whole process. I am not sure whether there is already existing tools.

I was thinking of using a code generator such as JavaParser to analyze a class and discover the properties mentioned using @Value and looking up them in the application.yaml and also do so in the openshift deployment config. For the class dependencies I need JavaParser to somehow find the classes in the same project and also in the relevant jars.

I have a gut feeling there might be a similar tool already existing. Need help in identifying this tool.